# c# JSON SerializeObject with Custom List

Tags: c#, json, list

I have an JSON Object like this:

```
    public class RootObject
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string ChannelType { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public List<ImageInfos> ImageInfos { get; set; }
    public bool IsInMixedFolder { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string DateModified { get; set; }
    public string DateLastSaved { get; set; }
    public List<object> LockedFields { get; set; }
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<string> Studios { get; set; }
    public List<string> Genres { get; set; }
    public ProviderIds ProviderIds { get; set; }
}
```

With ImageInfos like this:

```
    public class ImageInfos
{
    private string Path;
    private string Type;
    private string DateModified;

    public ImageInfos(string Path, string Type, string DateModified)
    {
        this.Path = Path;
        this.Type = Type;
        this.DateModified = DateModified;
    }
```

I am trying to fill the json ImageInfos-List with values and serialize it to a new string:

```
            jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

            List<ImageInfos> newInfos = new List<ImageInfos>();
            newInfos.Add(new ImageInfos("Test", "Test", "Test"));
            jsonObject.ImageInfos = newInfos;
            string newJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject);
```

But the new json looks like that:

> "{\"Number\":\"35\",\"ChannelType\":\"TV\",\"ServiceName\":\"DVBLink\",\"ImageInfos\":[{}],\"IsInMixedFolder\":false,\"Name\":\"13th Street HD\",\"Id\":\"466ab1fb9be4f77e65ad2b229a15c326\",\"DateCreated\":\"2015-09-14T12:55:51.4081476Z\",\"DateModified\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z\",\"DateLastSaved\":\"2015-10-17T13:34:37.4214116Z\",\"LockedFields\":[],\"ParentId\":\"00000000000000000000000000000000\",\"Studios\":[],\"Genres\":[],\"ProviderIds\":{\"ProviderExternalId\":\"13250000\"}}"

Why is ImageInfos empty in the new JSON string ?

Comment: All the properties of `ImageInfos` are private.  Json.NET will not serialize them by default.  To force it to serialize private properties, add the  `[JsonProperty]` attribute to each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the properties of `ImageInfos` are private.  Json.NET will not serialize them by default, so the resulting JSON shows an empty object.

To force Json.NET to serialize private properties, add the  [`[JsonProperty]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute to each:

```
public class ImageInfos
{
    [JsonProperty]
    private string Path;
    [JsonProperty]
    private string Type;
    [JsonProperty]
    private string DateModified;

    public ImageInfos(string Path, string Type, string DateModified)
    {
        this.Path = Path;
        this.Type = Type;
        this.DateModified = DateModified;
    }
}
```

(Or, make them public).